# add two namespaces into same dom element

Tags: java, xml, xml-namespaces, xerces, xalan

I need create a dom document as this:

```
<namespace:Facturae xmlns:namespace="URI1" xmlns:namespace2="URI2">
    //<.......
</namespace:Facturae>
```

But the following code produce the error:

```
NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
```

The code is:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();     
Document document = builder.newDocument();

Element FacturaeElement = document.createElementNS("URI1", "Facturae");
document.appendChild(FacturaeElement);
FacturaeElement.setPrefix("namespace"); //First namespace OK

FacturaeElement.setAttributeNS("URI2", "xmlns:namespace2", "aaa");   //Generate error
//Rest of code
```

How I can put a second namespace into element??

Answer (score 0):

Searching more information I have reached the solution:

I use the normal setAtribute method (without namespace) indicating the name of the atribute with the xmlns prefix so: "xmlns:namespace2".

Then, I create the sub element with this the namespace and later put the prefix.

```
Element FacturaeElement = document.createElementNS("URI1", "Facturae");
document.appendChild(FacturaeElement);
FacturaeElement.setPrefix("namespace"); //First namecpace
FacturaeElement.setAttribute("xmlns:namespace2", "URI2"); //second namespace

//I create the subelement with a namespace
Element FileHeaderElement = document.createElementNS("URI2", "FileHeader");
FacturaeElement.appendChild(FileHeaderElement);
FileHeaderElement.setPrefix("namespace2");
```